# Slow DB connection generally on computer

Tags: sql-server, connection, ssms

Ok, I have a very strange problem that I cannot figure out.

When I'm connecting to a DB it's very slow.

Asking questions to a DB - no problem.
Open new windows in SSMS - no problem.
and so on and so on.

Let me explain:
When I'm starting up SSMS it's normal speed (quite slow cause I have addons and stuff, but I'll get to that). But when SSMS has fully started it asks which server I want to connect to and when I choose one and press CONNECT I get a ~12 second wait time before I can start using the server.

This ~12 seconds is quite a long wait time. It's only on network servers, not when I'm connecting to my own SQL on my computer, then it goes blazingly fast.

Ok, so when I finally am connected I can use the DB without trouble. I can open new windows and ask queries and it takes normal time.

So - why do I bother about a ~12 second start time that happens very few times a day? Because when I debug my webpage that I'm developing I have like 10-12 calls to a database to load one page (not very uncommon) and every time it asks a question from the webpage is a new connection. Thus a page takes more than 100 seconds to load. When you are developing a page it is extremely frustrating to have to wait that long each time you want to check something.
God forbid I want to run the debugger at the same time, that doubles the time again, ending up on over 200 seconds (way over even) for every page load.

What have I done:
1 - Checked the connection time in SSMS 2016 with lots of addons - slow.
2 - Checked the connection time in SSMS 2017 with no addons - slow.
3 - Checked the connection time when debugging page - slow.
4 - Checked the connection time when starting Sentry1 - slow.
5 - Checked my internet connection carefully - it's 1000/100 and works well.
5b - I have checked the latency to the server and it's very low with a ping that runs over several hours with 0 packet loss and 8-9 ms response time.
5c - DNS lookup is blazingly fast and reverse lookup resloves correctly.
6 - Connected to the database server (i.e the windows machine) with RDP - fast, no problem.
7 - Checked my connection speed between my computer and the database server - fast, no problem.
8 - Checked other people on the exact same network - fast, no problem with any of the above.
9 - Disabled the service CEIP (Customer Experience Program, was that the name?) for SQL that was recommended by one site, still slow.
10 - Patched the CEIP registry key to make sure that not only the service is disabled but also the actual registry, still slow.

So, to summarize:
Connecting to a db is slow.
Opening new windows in SSMS is fast.

This started happening about 6-7 days ago and before that it was blazingly fast. I did update Visual Studio around the same time but I don't know for sure that it coincides with the start of my problem.

Help!

**Edit, addition:**
I tested the exact same setup on another computer - works perfectly. Unfortunately I cannot work from that computer :(
There is a lot of ram memory in the computer that has a problem.

Comment: I also tested to switch to a 4G connection and it behaves the same.

Comment: did u checked Memory of local computer where you are trying to connect ssms ?

Comment: Memory of the local computer is 16gb with tons of free mem to use.

Comment: I suggest you focus on performance of host name resolution and authentication (in the case of Windows authentication). Ping by remote host name and try a SQL account instead if your current using Windows authentication.

Comment: I am using windows authentication. Sadly there was no difference in SQL Server authentication (great idea though, thanks). But both of these issues are a bit over my head. I'll talk to my support people and forward these ideas to them.

Comment: I give up. Now I'll reinstall my entire computer.